# Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]

Tags: odbc, informix, avaya

Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.

```
ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Unable to load locale categories.
ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Unable to load locale categories.
```

The test connection is successful in DSN configuration, but when I open Visual Studio to run an ETL under this, the connection with Avaya Active CMS gives me this error.

I tried uninstalling and installing a couple of times but it still gives me same error.  I am hoping for a solution to this issue so that I can run my Visual Studio ETL.

Comment: If you are using SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) which is what is normally use to run ETL packages it could be you have not set the proper environment for whatever user (usually Local System Account) that runs the SSIS service.
When you test a DSN you are doing that with your current (logged) user, but SSIS may be running as someone else and that someone else may not have all the required environment and settings to run the Informix ODBC connection.  Make sure you have PATH and INFORMIXDIR properly set as System variables so any user will be able to find Informix resources.